# CoreData: fetching instance with second degree condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, fetch

My CoreData structure is like this:

```
A.setWithBs ->> B
B.setWithCs ->> C
```

Now, knowing only A, I need to fetch the only B in setWithBs that links to a specific C. Can this be done elegantly with single fetch?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question, in particular what is meant with "... that links to a specific C", then we can help better.

Comment: Sorry about that. Before I got around to checking back here, I had to edit the CD structure. Specific C meant a C that satisfied certain known criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with the "self in" and "Subquery" request. Haven't tested this special case, but this should be the way you have to go

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@ AND SUBQUERY(setWithCs, $sc, $sc == %@).@count > 0", A.setWithBs, C];
```

Comment: This was the suggestion that got me on the right track. With the edited CD I ended up with building two predicates and joining them as one NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have also defined the *inverse relationship* (which you should)

```
B.inA --> A, C.inB --> B
```

then you can execute the following fetch request:

```
A *theAObject = ...;
C *theCObject = ...;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"B"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(inA = %@) AND (ANY setWithCs = %@)",
         theAObject, theCObject];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

It fetches all "B" objects that are related to the given "A" object (via the inverse relationship "inA") and also related to the given "C" object (via the to-many relationship
"setWithCs").